# Arduino ethernet shield MAC address

Tags: arduino

I have purchased an ethernet shield for my project and it has a sticker on it which I believe is the MAC address that I need to enter into my sketch but I am not sure how to translate it into a MAC address.

The sticker has the number 664860.

Im not sure how to turn this into a real mac address like `{  0xFE, 0xED, 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF }` for example.

Any help would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter what the MAC address is as long as it's unique on any given ethernet segment.

If you want to use what's on the sticker then just convert it to base 16 (hex) 0xA251C and break it up into pairs of digit:

0A, 25, 1C

use this for the last 3 digits of the MAC address

`{ 0xFE, 0xED, 0xDE, 0x0A, 0x25, 0x1C }`

Comment: Thank you that really helped